# Sequelize order by column name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to order by column name in Sequelize

Here is my model

```
var Milestones = sequelize.define('milestones', {
  milestoneId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  data: Sequelize.JSON,
  repository: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

Database is PostegreSql 9.5

```
var dialect = 'postgres',
    protocol = 'postgres';

var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.database, dbConfig.user, dbConfig.password, {
  host: dbConfig.host,
  dialect: dialect,
  protocol: protocol,
  dialectOptions: {
    timeout: 30
  },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 30000,
    maxConnections: 5,
    maxIdleTime: 30
  },
  logging: false
});
```

Here is my query

```
models.Milestones.findAll({
      where: {
        repository: req.body.repository
      },
      order: 'milestoneId'
    }).then(function (values) {
      // do something
    });
```

Here is my error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "milestoneid" does not exist
```

So problem is that I wanna order by `milestoneId` but Sequelize is actually trying to order by `milestoneid` (notice the lack of camel case).

If I change to order by `repository` everything works, so the issue at this point seems to be related to the conversion to lowercase by Sequelize.

Any suggestions other than to rename the column in database to lowercase?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your model with a field and it will be fine

```
var Milestones = sequelize.define('milestones', {
  milestoneId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    field: 'milestoneId'
  },
  data: Sequelize.JSON,
  repository: Sequelize.STRING
});
```

EDIT:

also update the ordering with

```
order: ['milestoneId']
```

Comment: This should work, and also should be `milestoneId`, not `milestonesId`

Comment: Field actually played no role in this, but changing the order did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PostGreSQL and Oracle (with Sequelize-Oracle).
Sequelize automatically adds quotes for many parameters.

Do you have "quoteIdentifiers" option turned off ? (default is on).

Maybe the problem isn't :
- order by milestoneid or order by milestoneId
But instead it can be :
- order by 'milestoneid' (with quotes causing the issue).

The doc says :

> [options.quoteIdentifiers=true] : Boolean, Set to false to make table names and attributes case-insensitive on Postgres and skip double quoting of them.